# regexp to match text between . " and blank line

Tags: javascript, regex

i'm new to regexp and I'm stuck with trivial parsing task;
Giving following structure i need regexp that matches all text between empty lines, so i could iterate through array of matches, and parse each item as a question

```
id1. "question title 1"
* variant one
* variant two
* three // comment

id2. "question title 2"
+ variant one
+ two
+ three

id3. "Anoter question title"
another variant
```

Comment: Wait, you just need to split the strings by spaces?

Comment: In other words, do you want a reg exp that matches non blank lines... ?

Comment: actually by blank lines

Comment: that is what i want - to Buddha

Comment: This can be useful to you.. http://regexpal.com/

Comment: My answer is not correct if you want to split by blank lines. Do you want to match both question line and answer lines? If so, Please reply back, i will fix the answer.

Comment: yes both question and answer lines should be matched as one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\. ".*` this will give you `. "question title 1"` as one of the match. You can read from fourth char to last but one.

I couldn't figure out a way to match both question and answer line using regular expression. Because, this regular expression will match multiple lines but `\. "[\s\S]+` but it will match until end of the string matching all questions and answers into a single string.

If we assume that the answers will always start with either + or *, Another alternative is to use `(\. ".*)|([\*\+].*)` This will match both questions and answers. However questions and answers will be separate matches.

Another way is to split the string using `id. "` This will give each of your question and answer into another string. However you may have to remove the `"` at the end of the question manually.

Another way I can imagine is splitting entire string using `^\s*$` . This will split the string using blank line and give you both question and answer as one single group. I hope this helps.